# updating footer in radgrid thourgh checkbox selection

Tags: c#, radgrid

I designed a radgrid using telerik controls which has some checkboxes and a footerrow.

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGridCustomers" runat="server"  
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None"  
                    Height="300px"  ShowFooter="true">
  <HeaderTemplate>
               <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" runat="server"   
                  OnCheckedChanged="ToggleSelectedState" AutoPostBack="true" />
  </HeaderTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxSelectedCustomer" runat="server" 
         OnCheckedChanged="ToggleRowSelection"/>
        </ItemTemplate>
         <ItemStyle Width="25px" Wrap="true" />
         <HeaderStyle Width="25px" />
    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
     <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Customers_Id" 
        FilterControlAltText="Filter column column" HeaderText="Id" 
        UniqueName="column" Visible="true">

    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="NominatedLoad" 
        FilterControlAltText="Filter column1 column" HeaderText="Nominated MW" 
        UniqueName="NominatedLoad" Aggregate="Sum">
            <HeaderStyle Wrap="true" Width="75px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
         <ItemStyle Width="75px" />
    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
```

So, as you can see I have ID, Name(did not put code here, thought it would be unnecessary), nominated field. Nominated field has a aggregate attribute.By default, I would load the grid with all checkboxes checked in the grid. Now, the problem is whenever the user unchecks a checkbox, the value in the footer should be updated automatically. So, i started writing this event

```
   protected void ToggleRowSelection(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((sender as CheckBox).NamingContainer as GridItem).Selected = (sender as 
            CheckBox).Checked;
        GridFooterItem footer = (GridFooterItem)
                   RadGridCustomers.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.Footer)[2];
        int totalLoad = Convert.ToInt32(footer["ActualLoad"].Text.Split(':')[1]);
        CheckBox chk = FindControl("CheckBoxSelectedCustomer") as CheckBox;
        foreach (GridDataItem data in RadGridCustomers.MasterTableView.Items)
        {
            if (chk.Checked == true)
            {
                //footer["ActualLoad"].Text = footer.Attributes.Add('Aggregate',                 }
        }
```

but i kind of was struck at the bottom if block not knowing how to update the footer row.can you please let me know how to finish this.

Also, kindly let me know whether this situation needs tobe done using jquery or on C#?(i mean te best possible way)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible!
you have to put the aggregate as custom! and use this 2 function(they are an example please adapt your code to it)

```
Public void RgDueBalance_CustomAggregate(object sender, GridCustomAggregateEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Result = 0;
        }
        protected void CheckBox1_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridFooterItem footerItem = rgDueBalance.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.Footer)[0] as GridFooterItem;
            double pageSum = double.Parse(footerItem["MontMI"].Text.Replace("Total:", ""));
            CheckBox checkBox = sender as CheckBox;
            GridDataItem dataItem = checkBox.NamingContainer as GridDataItem;
            double value = double.Parse(dataItem["MontMI"].Text);

            if (checkBox.Checked)
            {
                pageSum += value;
            }
            else
            {
                pageSum -= value;
            }
            footerItem["MontMI"].Text = "Total: " + pageSum;
        }
```

What this does is when you check one check box it sums the value, or the opposite for the unchecking.
hope it helps you!